# When was the weekend changed in Jordan?

Tags: middle-east

I have been researching this (online) for a while with no success. I know for sure that the weekend in Jordan was changed from Thursday/Friday to Friday/Saturday. But I was not able to find any reference on when this change was made. There is  [one website](http://archive.wfn.org/2000/01/msg00078.html) that seems to indicate that the change occurred in early 2000, but not clearly.

The question is: are there any references at all that indicates when this change took place?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Associated Press International
Saturday, December 25, 1999

"Jordan shifts weekend to Friday-Saturday"

AMMAN, Jordan

Jordan said Saturday it will change the weekend for government offices to Fridays and Saturdays instead of Thursdays and Fridays, putting it more in step with world business.

**State-owned Petra news agency said the change goes into effect starting the week of Saturday, Jan. 8.**

It was not immediately clear if the government decision also applied to schools and universities.

The government had on Oct. 7 switched from a Friday-only weekend to Thursday-Friday. Friday is the Muslim Sabbath.

Economists had argued that that complicated commercial activity, because banks and the diplomatic corps had already taken Saturday as a holiday.

Businessmen said the Thursday-Friday weekend isolated the country from the Western world, where the weekend is normally Saturday and Sunday.

Financial institutions and many private businesses had introduced a Friday-Saturday weekend starting last March.

The other day weekend in Jordan is Friday, the Muslim day of prayer.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: @jak123 There is no link. API news archives are only available to professional subscribers and accredited journalists. If you go to a large library they have access to a news service that will include API historical filings. If you have access to Agence France archives (also available only to libraries and professionals), you can finding a similar news release dated December 12, 1999.

Comment: What about a screenshot?

Comment: @jak123 I added a screen shot.

Comment: Thanks Tyler! Unless an answer with a direct link is given, I will grant you the bounty tomorrow.

Comment: Very well done!